# NSArray filterArrayUsingPredicate never returning/ blocking execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array of custom objects based on the `name` property of those objects.

To make sure everything was working, I simply used this which should match with exactly 1 element in the array:

```
NSLog(@"Length before %lu", (unsigned long) [self.mutableAvailableSources count]);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == CNN)"];
[self.mutableAvailableSources filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"Length after %lu", (unsigned long) [self.mutableAvailableSources count]);
```

This should log

```
Length before 9
Length after 1
```

However, it only logs

```
Length before 9
```

And then it stops executing. Nothing past the line filtering the array gets executed. I tried placing a breakpoint on the second `NSLog(..);` statement, but it never reaches. If I place a breakpoint on the line filtering the array however, it stops and I can confirm that both the array and the predicate exists.

What is going on here?

This is happening in a asynchronous block by the way, so the app never freezes. But the rest of the code in the block doesn't execute.

Comment: Is the a possibility that the containing object is destroyed before the block completes?

Comment: No, it's a shared object (singleton instance) so it should not be deallocated (/destroyed). If I remove the line that filters the array, everything else works fine - it keeps executing until the end of the block. So there's something about the line that filters the array

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? Should it be `filterUsingPredicate` rather than `filterArrayUsingPredicate` if not can you show the source for `filterArrayUsingPredicate`.  Note `NSMutableArray` isn't thread safe so you shouldn't manipulate it in multiple threads without at least `@synchronized`

Comment: Yes, that was just a typo. I changed the question to reflect the correct method `filterUsingPredicate:`, but I've actually tried `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` also and assigning that to a new array, but no luck. 

I didn't know `NSMutableArray` wasn't thread safe, but I'm already adding to and manipulating that array earlier in this block with no issues so I don't think that's the problem. I'll add the ´@synchronized´ though to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Paulw11 `Onik IV`'s answer actually fixed it. It was a simple error in the predicate which caused the function to never return. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this :

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == 'CNN'"];
```

In predicates, you must use query languages, in this case is a string literal: in Query languages two options: 'stringLitareal' or "stringLiteral" but this second don´t work because " is used in objective-C, you need to scape the ", that´s it: name == \"CNN\". You can test this, is the same:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == \"CNN\""];
```

More Info: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#literals

Parentheses is not a problem (Query language). This also work : @"(name == 'CNN')"

Comment: Wow I can't believe this worked... Thanks! So I guess it just never finished executing with the parentheses. Could you explain why that wouldn't work?

Comment: I think a better change would be: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", @"CNN"];`